# mysql query optimization strategy on single table covering index

Tags: mysql

currently i am working on mysql query optimization . My mysql table contain 200 million records.
After doing lots of google i finally decide to use covering index.

So, i made a index in this order

```
alter table table_name add index
     index_name(MODEL, COUNTRY, REGION, NETWORK, E_TUAL,
                ECHS, DEVID, COUNTRY_CODE, SOURCE);
```

when i run this query efficiency is good as compare to previous

```
SELECT E_TUAL,ECHS, DEVID, MODEL, COUNTRY, REGION, COUNTRY_CODE, NETWORK, SOURCE
FROM table_name
WHERE model = 'fox | s453' AND country = 'india' AND
      E_TUAL <= '1435755600' AND
      E_TUAL >= '1433163600'
```

ORDER BY E_TUAL DESC 
   LIMIT 101 OFFSET 0;

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ref  | genrl  | genrl | 131     | const |  239 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+------+-----------------------------+
```

But This query is worst compare to older one (before index)

```
SELECT E_TUAL,ECHS, DEVID, MODEL,COUNTRY, REGION, COUNTRY_CODE, NETWORK, SOURCE
FROM table_name
WHERE model = 'fox | s453' AND
      country is not null AND
      E_TUAL <= '1435755600' AND
      E_TUAL >= '1433163600'
ORDER BY E_TUAL DESC
LIMIT 101 OFFSET 0;

+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | range | genrl  | genrl | 131     | NULL | 1105 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

i write country is not null to maintain order so mysql optimizer use index

plz help how to improve efficiency when some of column field is absent and
to make use of index what can i do ?

I am not good in english. so for any mistake i am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Dispense with the covering index and use two separate indexes:

```
alter table table_name add index index_name(MODEL, COUNTRY, E_TUAL);
```

for the first query.  And:

```
alter table table_name add index index_name(MODEL, E_TUAL);
```

A covering index might provide marginal improvement, but it will use a lot of space.  Instead, focus on the `WHERE` clauses and then the `ORDER BY` if you can use those for the index.

As a note:  your ordering of the columns was not optimal for either query.

Comment: my query build dynamic so i think this is not a good solution

Comment: The issue with your covering index is that any part of the index after a column that is no being checked will be of no use. Hence in your first query it is only the model and country columns that use the index. This suggestion by @GordonLinoff is aimed at generating indexes that will be required for your specific queries. But it the fields in the queries are random then that isn't going to work.

Comment: @booksapp . . . I can only answer based on the information in the question.  And your question has two queries and no discussion of dynamic sql.